# What does CASE SUM(total_of_A) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(B) / SUM(total_of_A) END mean

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, case-expression

Trying to understand the `CASE` (Transact-SQL) expression, but ended up with lot of confusion. Can anyone please explain the following statement in simple words?

```
CASE SUM(total_of_A) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(B) / SUM(total_of_A) END;
```

I [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) the following, but it doesn't clear up the confusion

```
CASE input_expression 
    WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
[ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Comment: this looks like someone is trying to avoid a divide by zero.

Comment: When sum of total of A is 0,return 0 if not 0 then return the sum of b over the sum of total of a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means

Calculate `SUM(B) / SUM(total_of_A)` only if the sum of `total_of_A` is not `0` because that would lead to a *divide by zero* exception.

It works like this

```
case <check SUM(total_of_A)>
     when <result of check is 0?>
     then <output 0>
     else <output the result of SUM(B) / SUM(total_of_A)>
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In `SQL Server` dividing by zero causes the following error:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Divide by zero error encountered.

So, the `case statement` is use for avoiding such cases.

Anyway, I guess this is wrong as `value / 0` is not `0`. I like the following check more:

```
SUM(B) / NULLIF(SUM(total_of_A), 0)
```

as it is shorter and returns `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This reads as 
If the sum of the column named total_of_A is 0 then the result of this case statement is 0 else the result of this case statement is the sum of the column named b divided by the sum of the column named total_of_A